# Unable To Integrate Infinite Scroll to existing working JSON script

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, cordova

I have developed a phonegap application where i have a page photos.html which fetches the photos from my server with the help of JSON.

I have managed to fetch all the photos stored in my MySQL database on the server with JSON, the only thing i couldn't achieve after trying all the infinite scroll plugins is the integration of Infinite Scroll to my existing JSON script.

Currently my JSON script is showing all the images stored in database in one go which making the page slower. I simply want that the by default 8 posts should be displayed and once user scrolls the page the next 8 should display and so on until the last entry in database.

Any idea how can i achieve that. Below is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } 
.embed-container img { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 5%; width: 90%; height: 100%; }
.btnamit4u
{
width:90%;
left:5%;
position:relative;
height:100%;
color:#fff;
background:#E66113;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:10px;
border-radius:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-top:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://www.amit4uservices.com/hh/json.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "";

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<div class='embed-container'><img src='" + 
        arr[i].url +
        "'/> <br></div>";
        out += " <button class='btnamit4u' onclick=\"window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Boliye , Hamare Hanuman', null, '"+ arr[i].url + "', 'http://goo.gl/x37m8R')\">Share It</button>";
    }
    //out += "</div>";
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and tried making something, of course without a fiddle it's sort-of.

Edit: fixed code, working now.

check it out:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://www.amit4uservices.com/hh/json.php";
var currIndex = 0;
var arr;
var myDiv = document.getElementById("id01");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        arr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(8);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(elementsToCreate) {
    var i;
    var out = "";

    for(i = 0; i < elementsToCreate && ((currIndex+1) < arr.length); i++, currIndex++) {
        out += "<div class='embed-container'><img src='" + 
        arr[currIndex].url +
        "'/> <br></div>";
        out += " <button class='btnamit4u' onclick=\"window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Boliye , Hamare Hanuman', null, '"+ arr[currIndex].url + "', 'http://goo.gl/x37m8R')\">Share It</button>";
    }
    //out += "</div>";
    myDiv.innerHTML += out;
}

document.addEventListener("scroll",function(ev){
    if(1000 > (document.body.scrollHeight - document.body.scrollTop)){
        myFunction(8);
    }
},false);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/12j3mgku/

Comment: No luck brother... There is no impact on scroll and now its showing only 6 images out of 11 images. Any other thing we can work out with ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the response you get from the ajax so I can imitate it?

Comment: you can simply save my code with .html and you will get to know the response and what i want to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: Brother thanks for editing the code.Its almost working with just an issue left ; that when we scroll down it shows all the remaining photos in one go, Instead it should display them in the set of 8 - 8 -8 etc... anything i can edit with ?

Comment: Infinite scroll means that you keep scrolling.. if you don't want the infinite scrolling and just change those 8 it's just change `myDiv.innerHTML += out;` to `myDiv.innerHTML = out;`